# Best Way To Add Text Falling From The Sky In Order?

Tags: text-object

Ok So I have multiple pieces of text in the sky and they are falling down on a rigid body plane (the floor) and it's set to passive not active.  The problem is I don't want ALL of the text to hit the floor at the same time.

The 3D text is set as rigid too and it's set as active (so it falls).  The way I've gotten text to hit the floor at different times is by simply varying the heights of the text falling (text closer to the passive rigid plane will hit first).

I don't like this though.  I wish there was some way using keyframes etc. that I could change from passive to active so I could control exactly when the 3D text would start falling.

Is there any way to do that?  Thanks guys

Comment: It is and that answers my questions I just couldn't find an answer on here case closed.  Thank you!  Thanks for directing me to the right spot!

Comment: Right click the active/passive property and you will be able to keyframe it.